# Next.js with pkg. Syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'flow, typescript'

Tags: javascript, node.js, dockerfile, next.js, zeit-pkg

I use next.js with [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) in my project based on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@evenchange4/deploy-a-commercial-next-js-application-with-pkg-and-docker-5c73d4af2ee) but when I run pkg command I get an error:

```
> Error! This experimental syntax requires enabling
  one of the following parser plugin(s): 'flow, typescript' (13:7)

  /app/node_modules/ast-types-flow/lib/types.js
```

Pkg command:

`pkg . -t node13-linux-x64 -o build`

Pkg version: 4.4.8

I tried to add options but still doesn't work:

```
"pkg": {
  "assets": [".next/**/*"],
  "scripts": [".next/dist/**/*.js"],
  "options": ["experimental-modules"]
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed unnecessary packages and the problem is gone =| (react-scripts, storybook). Also `options` is not required