# How to enable parser plugins 'flow, typescript' for a React app using npm pkg

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to use the npm command:

```
pkg .
```

To create executable files for each OS to test my React app (a simple localhost:), index.js page

Although I get the error:

```
> Error! This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'flow, typescript' (13:7)
  \***\node_modules\ast-types-flow\lib\types.js
```

This could be becuase I have referenced a blank bin.js file but I think something else is needed...

I believe that a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778373/next-js-with-pkg-syntax-requires-enabling-one-of-the-following-parser-plugins) 
Although I am unsure of the answered reply, by what 'removed unnecessary packages means'.

Could someone point me to the steps I need to take to fix this?

The start of my package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "web_application",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "bin": "bin.js", //needs some file content?
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [".next/**/*"],
    "scripts": [".next/dist/**/*.js"] //Unsure of exactly what I need to define here
  },
```

Many thanks